# Questions and answer solving books on computer network and finite automata

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata

I was looking for a problem and solutions books over the internet for data computer netwrok and Finite automata theory to enhance my problem solving skills, couldn't find out any one as i needed.

Do you help me here?

Thanks,

Comment: MCQs or Theory or numericals?

Comment: MCQ and mathematical problem/solved books!

Comment: your question is closed and no one can answer it now..

Comment: @BhushanFirake But vote up can reopen the question..right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming towards MCQ books, then following books can help you out:

1. G.K.Publishers Book for GATE
2. [Timothy Willaims "MCQs for COmputer Science](http://www.tatamcgrawhill.com/html/9780071077699.html)"

   **For Autometa:**

   HOP CRAFT AND ULLMAN,

   HORWITZ AND SAHANI,

   PETER LINZ

   **For Network Numericals:**

   TENNENBAUM,

   WILLAIM STALLINGS,

   FROUZEN

These are the finest books for concepts and numericals but I dont remember their titles. So here are author names. Hope this helped out.

Comment: Okay! any problem and solutions books. G.K publisher books are not upto the mark,as lots of solved answers are wrong there!

Comment: try to get the solutions of Tennenbaum, stallings and forouzon.They are all available on internet. Just give a google to it.

Comment: Are you preparing for GATE 2013?

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU: Then start using Made Easy Solutions or their sample papers .They are just awesome..i got maximum with them at my time...

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU Don't go for `G.K.Publishers Book ` if you really wants to score high in GATE

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes I know that books contains wrong answers.Any better suggestions from your side? please do create your answer(new answer post) with your suggestions!

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU Best thing do the question given at end of every chapter in Pearson's book..Do you know about `IES Made-Easy`or `ACE` collect material....Also good is to solve last 10+ year  papers.

Comment: Can you give a vote for Re-open?

Comment: If any online material or link of such books you have,give me the link please!